# What does ”they were an insult to the fabric of space/time itself” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The last part of following paragraph is **they were an insult to the fabric of space/time itself**.
what the writer want to say?

> Elliot’s work performance suffered. Tasks that were once a breeze to him now required mountains of concentration and effort. Simple decisions, such as whether to use a blue pen or a black pen, would consume him for hours. He would make basic errors and leave them unfixed for weeks. He became a scheduling black hole, missing meetings and deadlines as if they were an insult to the fabric of space/time itself.

Comment: It's a fairly unusual (maybe "geeky") metaphoric usage playing with concepts from theoretical physics. Ordinary people use related expressions such as ***He's a waste of space***, but this one's definitely a bit weird. The idea is that the guy is so worthless / objectionable that not only all other people, but *reality itself* would be better off without him.

Comment: [...here's](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22blot+on+the+fabric+of+reality%22&oq=%22blot+on+the+fabric+of+reality%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.1472337j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) a reference to someone / something being a ***blot on the fabric of reality*** (highly undesirable).

Comment: It was so useful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually, I didn't read the context very carefully. It's not "the guy" (Elliot) who's being judged as worthless / contemptible. The meaning here is that Elliot treated business meetings and project deadlines contemptuously (by not even showing up to meetings, for example). But presumably that would also make Elliot *himself* pretty worthless from the point of view of his employers and co-workers, so the total net meaning is similar anyway.